# JSTL: for Each loop to iterate over collection

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

following is my snippet, which was working good untill I migrated from spring 2 to spring 3 and Jstl 1.1 to jstl 1.2. Now, its not working and keep on giving the error 
`fEvents cannot found on object location`

```
 <c:forEach items="${location.fEvents}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <tr><td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].hostName" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].directory" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].userName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="fEvents[${loop.index}].password" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

need to iterate the ftpEvents and show them on jsp
Any suggestion is appreciated!!!

Comment: What type is `location`?  Can you post the relevant classes/interfaces?

Comment: Location and FtpEvents have one to many relation...just need to know how to loop through the collection of objects...if I use...`fEvents[0].hostName`..it works..but I have 5 values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the object called "location" does not have an fEvents property.  Is it actually called ftpEvents?  Do you need to just change the variable name?

Even with that, though, you'll probably want to do something more like this:

```
 <c:forEach items="${location.ftpEvents}" var="item">
    <tr><td><form:input path="item.hostName" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="item.directory" size="30" maxlength="200"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="item.userName" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
    <td><form:input path="item.password" size="20" maxlength="20"/></td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

...you don't need to even use the loop.index at all, if I'm interpreting your code correctly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, you say that the problem is still there but you accepted the answer?  Is it still a problem, or not?

Comment: its not..resolved...it was an issue with property name..was using correctly in all the places except in the hibernate config file..had two fields of same name one for boolean and one for collection..need to change one of the property name!